# Rewrite Rule added but showing 404 rather than specified page

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have the following rewrite rule

```
function coaching_apply_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('^coaching/apply/', 'index.php?page_id=5156', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'coaching_apply_rule');
```

Reason for the rule is that `/coaching/` is an archive page for a custom post type. I would like my `/apply/` page to be a child of the archive page so when a user goes to `/coaching/apply/` the page at `/apply/` loads. I assume I can do this with the rewrite rule above. `5156` is the id of the `/apply/` page.

Using the rewrite analyzer plugin I can see my custom rewrite rule and it says it matches the `/coaching/apply/`url. But when I visit that url, I get a 404 page. Any thoughts as to why this isn't working?

Analyzer Results
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well this is silly but I figured it out. I removed the last `/` from the pattern and now it works as expected. Code is now...

```
add_rewrite_rule('^coaching/apply', 'index.php?page_id=5156', 'top');
```

Seems weird to me that `^coaching/apply` would work but not `^coaching/apply/` esp when entering `example.com/coaching/apply/` as the url works.